# Any idea why my parser test is returning this error?

Tags: c++, parsing, jenkins, boost

I have fixed the code in a cpp file for a GPS system but when I go to run a parser test on Jenkins, I receive this error:

> tests/nmea/nmea-parser-tests.cpp(28): [1;31;49merror: in "IsSupportedFormat/SupportedFormats": check isSupportedFormat("WPL") has failed[0;39;49m

Here is the code for the section of the error:

```
#include <iostream> // For debugging
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include "nmea/nmea-parser.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace GPS::NMEA
{
  bool isSupportedFormat(std::string theSentence)
  {
      
      unsigned startOfData = theSentence.find("P"); //gets the start of the data by finding the first P (which will be on the end of $GP)
      
      unsigned endOfData = theSentence.find(","); //gets the first comma (which will be straight after the data we need)
      string theData = theSentence.substr(startOfData + 1, endOfData - startOfData - 1); //this stores the data inbetween the P and then ,(this splits the data we need away from the full sentence)
      
      if (theData == "GLL") { //checks if the data reads GLL
          return true;
      }
      else if (theData == "WPL") { //checks if the data reads WPL
          return true;
      }
      else if (theData == "RMC") { //checks if the data reads RMC
          return true;
      }
      else if (theData == "GGA") { //checks if the data reads GGA
          return true;
      }
      else {
          return false; //If none of the data matches up correctly then this will return false.
      }
  }
```

I've tried re-writing the code and moving it around but for some reason "WPL" is the only one that fails the parser test.

Comment: PSA: Use `const std::string&` as a default string argument type.

Comment: Where are the other test cases? We can't know what the requirements are. We just know that the given implementation is incorrect for the given input, but the test failure already told you that. If we're to help you fix it, we should know what *other requirements* exist. Right now, replacing `bool isSupportedFormat(std::string const& s) { return s == "WPL"; }` will fix your test...

Answer (score 0):

because with theSentence == "WPL":

```
unsigned startOfData = theSentence.find("P"); //gets the start of the data by finding the first P (which will be on the end of $GP)
unsigned endOfData = theSentence.find(","); //gets the first comma (which will be straight after the data we need)
```

startOfData is 1 because that's the index of the P. endOfData is `std::string::npos` (the highest possible size_t)

```
string theData = theSentence.substr(startOfData + 1, endOfData - startOfData - 1); //this stores the data inbetween the P and then ,(this splits the data we need away from the full sentence)
```

`theSequence.substr(2, big number)` is "L".

```
if (theData == "GLL") { //checks if the data reads GLL
```

it doesn't

```
else if (theData == "WPL") { //checks if the data reads WPL
```

it doesn't

```
else if (theData == "RMC") { //checks if the data reads RMC
```

it doesn't

```
else if (theData == "GGA") { //checks if the data reads GGA
```

it doesn't

```
  else {
      return false; //If none of the data matches up correctly then this will return false.
  }
```

so the function returns false.

Comment: Sorry I'm not the most advanced with coding yet. How would I go about rectifying this issue?

Comment: @F02 You tell the computer to do what you want it to do, instead of what you don't want it to do :) I assumed you understood the error message, but maybe not - did you understand what the immediate problem is?